# posts on my theme get cut off at the side for smaller resolutions

Tags: css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

i have no idea how to code. and i was customizing my tumblr theme when i ran into a problem. everything is positioned correctly for my monitor resolution like so, [image: Image 1]

but as i always forget, the posts get cut off at smaller resolutions. 
[image: image 2]

i know it's because i moved the margin over, but i'm wondering how i can make these posts relative or fixed so that they show up when the resolution is scaled down for other users. Yet at the same time stay in the same preferred spot for my resolution which is 1920 x 1080.

i'm not sure if it's necessary to provide the html but here:

```
/* containers */

main {width:calc({select:post size}px + 400px);}

 .centerz {margin:0 auto;}
 .leftcont {left:0px; position:absolute;}
 .rightcont {position:absolute; right:-20px;}

 #postmargin {
z-index:1;
line-height:150%;
position:relative;
padding:20px 0px 50px 0px;
width:calc({select:post size}px + 40px);
}

.leftposts {margin-left:350px;}
.rightposts {margin-left:20px;}

/* posts */

.posts {
background:{color:Posts};
margin:80px 890px;
padding:0px;
transition:0.6s ease-in-out;
width:calc({select:post size}px + 20px);
-webkit-animation:fadein 1s;
animation:fadein 1s;
{block:IndexPage}border-bottom:1px solid {color:Permalinks and Asks}{/block:IndexPage}
 }

.posts img {
max-width:100%;
transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
{block:ifmonochromeimages}{block:indexpage}
-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
filter:grayscale(100%);
}

.posts:hover img {
-webkit-filter:grayscale(0%);
filter:grayscale(0%);
{/block:indexpage}{/block:ifmonochromeimages}
}

{block:iffadingimages}{block:indexpage}
.posts img {opacity:0.7;}
.posts:hover img {opacity:1;}
{/block:indexpage}{/block:iffadingimages}

.container {padding:10px;}
.text {padding:5px 10px;}
.singlepic {display:block;}
.tumblr_video_container {width:auto!important; height:auto!important;}

.photo {border-bottom:1px solid {color:Permalinks and Asks};}
.photo a {padding-bottom:0px; border-bottom:0px solid transparent;}
.text a, .sourcez a {border-bottom:1px solid {color:Borders};}
.text a:hover, .sourcez a:hover {border-color:{color:Links Hover};}
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks for reading!

Comment: Have you actually tried testing this from a mobile device? The default setting is for tumblr to use it's own custom mobile layout. If you want to override this you can, but you need to write css with media queries.

Comment: i test it with screenfly. this question isn't based for the tumblr mobile app. but for monitor resolutions lower than 1920 x 1080 such as my friend's monitor which is 1620 x 1050. i can position the posts to be in the center but i'd rather be able to have a code that can adjust the position of the posts for smaller resolutions.

Comment: Sorry, you need to write your own custom media queries, generally having margins of 315px and so on would not be considered very useful these days. If you use a mobile first approach this becomes much easier. As well as using % width, then your content will resize more smoothly between screen sizes. You are either stuck with this theme working on large screen and then having to reset alot of the styles (or at least edit them) for smaller screens, or potentially using a different theme.

Comment: Adding media queries is unnecessary, all that needs to happen is the post container being a distance from the right instead of the left